# How to plot a perfectly smooth sphere

Tags: python, matplotlib, surface, mplot3d, matplotlib-3d

I am trying to plot a perfectly smooth sphere in python using matplotlib. I have been using the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(1)    
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
x = np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))

ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, linewidth=0.0)

plt.show()
```

The plot I obtained is attached below:
[image: figure]

The figure generated consists of patches of rectangular surfaces on it. Is it possible to smoothen out the boundaries or make it indistinguishable and to make a perfectly smooth sphere?

Comment: The figure looks perfectly smooth to me. ???

Comment: How much smoother can it be?

Comment: Maybe you meant 'perfectly round'?

Comment: You could maybe make the sub-polygons smaller by providing a finer grid and/or setting `cstride` and `rstride` [see the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matplotlib plots 3d surfaces by breaking them down into small sub-polygons of equal colour, as is explained in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots), hence your result is not really a surprise. In order to get a smoother surface, you have to provide more data points. There is, however, a small twist, which is that `plot_surface()` may not use all the data you provide. This is controlled with the `cstride` and `rstride` keywords. How the defaults are calculated is not quite clear to me, but below a little example that demonstrates the effect:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

fig,axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2,nrows=2,subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))

N=50
stride=2
ax = axes[0,0]
u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, N)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, N)
x = np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, linewidth=0.0, cstride=stride, rstride=stride)
ax.set_title('{0}x{0} data points, stride={1}'.format(N,stride))

N=50
stride=1
ax = axes[0,1]
u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, N)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, N)
x = np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, linewidth=0.0, cstride=stride, rstride=stride)
ax.set_title('{0}x{0} data points, stride={1}'.format(N,stride))

N=200
stride=2
ax = axes[1,0]
u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, N)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, N)
x = np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, linewidth=0.0, cstride=stride, rstride=stride)
ax.set_title('{0}x{0} data points, stride={1}'.format(N,stride))

N=200
stride=1
ax = axes[1,1]
u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, N)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, N)
x = np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, linewidth=0.0, cstride=stride, rstride=stride)
ax.set_title('{0}x{0} data points, stride={1}'.format(N,stride))

plt.show()
```

The resulting figure looks like this:

[image: result of the above code]

As you can see, the outcome of the plot is sensitive to both the density of your data and the `stride` keywords. Be careful though with the amount of data you provide -- `plot_surface()` can take up a considerable amount of time to provide a result. Hope this helps.