# How to plot many spheres and points with Python

Tags: python, paint

I have a file which haves coordinates x,y,z and radius r of many spheres. I want to plot with python theses spheres and the  points (x,y,z). It doesn't have to be in 3D, it is good if it is in 2D (ignore the coordinate z, for example).

I don't even know how to start, any help?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're new to programming and not confident using matplotlib, you could try making the plot in a drawing package such as [Turtle graphics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html) or [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/docs/).  Have a go and see which you find easiest/best.

Answer (score 0):

You can use patches in Matplotlib to create circles. For example, using [this documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Circle.html).
In case that you would like to plot spheres in 3D, you can use [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51646768/13230625).